# convergence in distribution from convergence of norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Assume we have two sequences of random elements $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ taking values in some normes space $S$, defined on the same probability space. Next, assume we know that
$$
X_n \overset{d}{\to} X
$$
and
$$
||X_n-Y_{n}|| \overset{a.s.}{\to} 0.
$$

Is the following correct
$$
Y_n \overset{d}{\to} X?
$$

Remark. Convergence in distribution for random elements is

1)$\mathbb{E}[f(X_{n})] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ for all bounded uniformly continuous functions.

2)$\limsup_{n}\mathbb{P}[X_{n}\in F]\leq \limsup_{n}\mathbb{P}[X\in F]$ for all closed $F$.

3)$\liminf_{n}\mathbb{P}[X_{n}\in G]\geq \limsup_{n}\mathbb{P}[X\in G]$ for all closed $F$.

4)$\mathbb{P}[X_{n}\in A] \to \mathbb{P}[X\in A]$ for all $X$-continuity sets A.

Comment: How is convergence in distribution defined on the normed space $S$?

Comment: @angryavian , I updated the question

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: yes... I apologise... this is Theorem 3.1 from Billingsley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_{n,\epsilon} = \{\|X_n - Y_n\| < \epsilon\}$.
Let $f$ be a bounded uniformly continuous function. Let $\sup_{x \in S} |f(x)| \le B$.
We have
$$|E[f(Y_n)] - E[f(X)]|
\le  \big|E[f(Y_n) \mathbf{1}_{A_{n,\epsilon}}] - E[f(X)]\big|
+ \big|E[f(Y_n) \mathbf{1}_{A_{n,\epsilon}^c}]\big|.$$

The second term is bounded by $B\cdot P(A_{n,\epsilon}^c)$ which converges to zero.

For the first term, note that
$$E[f(Y_n) \mathbf{1}_{A_{n, \epsilon}}]
= E[f(X_n) \mathbf{1}_{A_{n, \epsilon}}] + E[(f(Y_n) - f(X_n)) \mathbf{1}_{A_{n, \epsilon}}]$$
so
$$\big|E[f(Y_n) \mathbf{1}_{A_{n,\epsilon}}] - E[f(X)]\big|
\le \big|E[f(X_n) \mathbf{1}_{A_{n, \epsilon}}] - E[f(X)]\big| + \epsilon.$$
Can you take it from here?